# Is there any learning service like Pluralsight but for design?

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations, interface-design, information-design

> Meet [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com). We are a group of serious developers. We are
>   also committed to creating the best training available. This mix of
>   training for developers, by developers is what rings true to our
>   customers.
>
> We call it hardcore developer training. You'll know it as superior
>   training that is relevant and pushes all the latest technologies.

Is there any service like this but for design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/) is the big hitter in the design world.

Comment: Historically Lynda was great for learning software, but not necessarily design concepts. But perhaps they do offer courses on that now.

Comment: Doesn't look like Pluralsight teaches at the abstract programming level either. More about specific languages and technology.

Comment: true. good point.

Comment: @plainclothes not entirely true. It is often very technical yes but you also learn software principles and a bunch of meta-programming stuff e.g. 'Career and Survival Strategies for Software Developers'. A pluralsight equivalent would include topics such as Design Principles, UX, Photoshop, Illustrator, you-name-it courses. +1 for Lynda.com.

Answer (score 4):

[Team Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com) and [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) have some interesting web design online courses (HTML + CSS). Not exactly graphic design, but might be of help. Treehouse is $25 a month and Codecademy is free.

PSD Tuts has a "[Teach yourself graphic design self-study course](http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/inspiration/teach-yourself-graphic-design-a-self-study-course-outline/)" that looks nice.

[Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) offers free courses from big Universities, with certificates and so. I haven't seen one about design, but they do offer things like Human-Computer Interaction.

Comment: I would advise any designer to learn the basics of html/css and coding for grids. It helps you be a better designer.

Answer (score 4):

I think plainclothes and yisela's answers cover the main resources of the type you're looking for, but you could also try free/open source resources that are more on the academic-side:

- [MIT OpenCourseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm)
- [CMU Open Learning Initiative](http://oli.cmu.edu/)
- [Harvard Open Learning Initiative](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative)
- [iTunes University](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/itunes-u/id40000000?mt=10) (distributes open learning materials from many schools),
- [P2PU](http://p2pu.org) (probably the less vetted of the resources listed here, but there's still some good courses on here by actual college professors),
- [edX](https://www.edx.org/) (provided by Harvard, MIT, Berkeley, Georgetown, etc.)
- the <s>[Open University](http://www.open.ac.uk/)</s> (edit: [Open University's OpenLearn](http://www.open.edu/openlearn/about-openlearn/try))
- [Academia.edu](http://academia.edu) (this is more of a social network for people to share research-related documents, but there's a lot of researchers/published authors/professors/etc. in the fields of IxD, HCI, branding, visual design, etc.)

I'm not 100% sure all of these have courses in design, but at least a few of them do. Unfortunately Khan Academy and Udacity, two other very good online education providers don't currently offer anything in design (unless you count [this KA video on "Intelligent Design"](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/evolution-and-natural-selection/v/intelligent-design-and-evolution)).

Comment: Great list! When I first heard about it, I loved the way "Open University" sounded, but unfortunately it's only for EU citizens / residents and the courses are **very** expensive.

Comment: @yisela: Ah, my mistake. I'd never actually checked out OU in depth aside from a quick look at their frontpage since they're always mentioned after my favorite BBC programs, but I guess the "Open" in their name is simply reference to the fact that they have _no entry requirements_, not that their course material is open source or free. They do have some free online materials, but it's under the OpenLearn section of their site.

Answer (score 2):

I did a brief comparison between Lynda and Pluralsight in my post which is currently ranked #1 on Google search. You can find it here:

[Lynda vs Pluralsight Online Software Training](http://simpledeveloper.com/lynda-vs-pluralsight-developer-training/)

In general, **Pluralsight** has been leaning towards the .NET side for a while but recently added some other courses like Java, Android, Ruby, and web development resources like jQuery, HTML5 and JavaScript Design Patterns.

**Lynda** on the other hand has a very extensive library of different technologies. You really can't go wrong with them because they don't lean on one thing as Pluralsight did in the beginning.

I would say both of them almost cost the same amount depending on the package you choose!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, welcome to GD! I have no issues with you linking to your own site, but could you post more than just a link? If your site goes down, your answer won't benefit anyone! A summary of your findings would be great.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up! I appreciate that. I will edit my answer to give more details and will do the same for future answers as well! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Pluralsight now owns DigitalTutors (design and 3d training), so there's that.

I've been on DT for a while and I'd recommend it. You get working files, quizes, and tests. One login for the complete tech and design libraries.

Have a look to see if they have courses you're into first as they are a little more geared to game and FX industries, though they do have Photoshop, illustrator, and InDesign tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

https://tutsplus.com/ 
A huge library of courses and eBooks to help you learn.
Web Development
Graphic Design
Motion Graphics
and more.

Answer (score 0):

I know this way late but pluralsight has dramatically grown with far more than just Microsoft related aspects. I have used much of what I learned for production apps. To me I find pluralsight geared towards IT practicioners, development and graphics (digital-tutors) where my take on lynda is more for end-users and power-users, although lynda has development courses as well. As for pluralsigh courses I know they use thought-leaders/well-know practioners and authors for various courses which validate the expertise in the training I receive.